# Click on Current Div to Hide the Others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jQuery's hide/show function, and I need to have it so when I click on a div, it shows that div, and hides the other.  Right now I have a SUPER janky, and SUPER inefficient way of doing it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".FifteenInfo").hide();
  $(".FourtyInfo").hide();
  $(".SixtyInfo").hide();
  $(".FifteenSpecs").hide();
  $(".FourtySpecs").hide();
  $(".SixtySpecs").hide();
    $(".Show15").click(function(){
      $(".FifteenInfo").show();
      $(".FifteenSpecs").show();
      $(".FourtySpecs").hide();
      $(".SixtySpecs").hide();
      $(".FourtyInfo").hide();
      $(".SixtyInfo").hide();
    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="buttonText Show15" width="200" height="300">DSL 6</button>
  <button class="buttonText Show40" width="200" height="300">DSL 10</button>
  <button class="buttonText Show60" width="200" height="300">DSL 15</button>
  <button class="buttonText Show40" width="200" height="300">DSL 25</button>
  <button class="buttonText Show60" width="200" height="300">DSL 50</button>
</div>
<div class="FifteenInfo border">
  <h1 class="Package">DSL 6</h1>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$29.99</h3>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$39.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
<div class="FifteenSpecs">
  <div class="monthlyUsage">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Usage</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage">150</h1>
    <p class="Gigabyte">GB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Download">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Download</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">6</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Upload">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Upload</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">800</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Kbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="orderNow">
    <button class="btn btntruespeed orderButton">Order Now!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="FourtyInfo border">
  <h1 class="Package">DSL 10</h1>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$29.99</h3>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$44.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
<div class="FourtySpecs">
  <div class="monthlyUsage">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Usage</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage">150</h1>
    <p class="Gigabyte">GB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Download">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Download</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">10</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Upload">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Upload</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">1</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="orderNow">
    <button class="btn btntruespeed orderButton">Order Now!</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

So is there a way to do this where it automatically checks which div you clicked on to show it, and to hide the others?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your HTML please.

Comment: Yes, it could be possible. But without your html it's hard to say. Show us more.

Comment: it is way easy but u need to show html code or a plunker link.

Comment: use another class which will be same for all that will help for jquery selector

Comment: How could you click on a hidden div, might be you are not clear with your goal.

Comment: @frnt he's not clicking on div's hes clicking on buttons to show divs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic way to do this is to link up the trigger element with its content using `data-*` attributes, along with giving all content elements a shared class so they can all be hidden in one.

```js
$('.content').hide();

$('.btn').click(function(){
    
  $('.content').hide()
  var target = $(this).data("target");
  $(target).show();
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-target="#content1">Show 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-target="#content2">Show 2</button>

<div id="content1" class="content">Content 1</div>
<div id="content2" class="content">Content 2</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
  $(".header").click(function() {

    //current div
    $header = $(this);

    //getting the next element
    $content = $header.next();

    //Hide all other than current div.
    $(".header").next().not($content).hide();

    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.toggle(500, function() {

      //change text of header based on visibility of content div
      $header.text(function() {

        //change text based on condition
        return $content.is(":visible") ? "Collapse" : "Expand";
      });
    });

  });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
}
.container div {
  width: 100%;
}
.container .header {
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  padding: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.container .content {
  display: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="header"><span>Expand</span>

  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <ul>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
      <li>This is just some random content.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: everyone that answered has been downvoted, probably some troll.

Comment: No, I downvoted this one for showing no effort to explain the problem, just some code with "try this". That does not make a good answer. You could have also made this code runnable - check out the snippet button. You could have also formatted your code so its a little readable.

Comment: @Jamiec thanx bro, i will try to improve myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".show").hide();
    $(".Show15").click(function(){
      $(".show").show();
    
    });
      $(".Show40").click(function(){
      $(".show").hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="buttons">
  <button class="buttonText Show15" width="200" height="300">DSL 6</button>
  <button class="buttonText Show40" width="200" height="300">DSL 10</button>
 
</div>
<div class="show">
<div class="FifteenInfo border">
  <h1 class="Package">DSL 6</h1>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$29.99</h3>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$39.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
<div class="FifteenSpecs">
  <div class="monthlyUsage">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Usage</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage">150</h1>
    <p class="Gigabyte">GB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Download">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Download</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">6</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Upload">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Upload</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">800</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Kbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="orderNow">
    <button class="btn btntruespeed orderButton">Order Now!</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="FourtyInfo border">
  <h1 class="Package">DSL 10</h1>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="monthlyPrice">\$29.99</h3>
  <div class="cableSpacer"></div>
  <h3 class="differentbandwidth">\$44.99 Unlimited</h3>
</div>
<div class="FourtySpecs">
  <div class="monthlyUsage">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Usage</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage">150</h1>
    <p class="Gigabyte">GB</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Download">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Download</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">10</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Upload">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Upload</h3>
    <h1 class="Usage" style="text-align: center;">1</h1>
    <p class="Megabyte">Mbps</p>
  </div>
  <div class="orderNow">
    <button class="btn btntruespeed orderButton">Order Now!</button>
  </div>
</div></div>
```

Comment: Please explain what you have changed and why. Just putting working code is not good enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a wrapper function to hide all similar elements using class pattern selectors

#### Sample Code

```js
$(".buttonText").click(function() {
  hideAll();
  var _showClass = $(this).attr("class").match(/Show.{2}/).pop();
  switch (_showClass) {
    case "Show15":
      toggleSection("Fifteen", true);
      break;
    case "Show40":
      toggleSection("Fourty", true);
      break;
    case "Show60":
      toggleSection("Sixty", true);
      break;
  }
});

function toggleSection(group, show) {
  var selector = "[class^=" + group + "]";
  show ? $(selector).show() : $(selector).hide();
}
```

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/v94qu943/2/).

**Note:** This will hide all similar classes. Eg: `toggleSection("Fourty", true)` this will hide elements with `FourtyInfo`, `FourtySpecs` and `Fourty...`

If you have such case, I suggest you try something like this:

```js
function toggleSection(group, show) {
  var sections = ["Info", "Specs"];
  var selector = sections.map(function(k) {
    return "." + group + k
  }).join();
  show ? $(selector).show() : $(selector).hide();
}
```

This will have more control as you have specified which classes are to be used.

[Sample Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/v94qu943/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shortest way .. works for all situations ..
script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // at the start..
    $('body').children().first().addClass('show');
    $('div').click(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('show');
        $(this).next().addClass('show');
    });
     // at the end ..
    $('body').children().last().click(function(){
        $('body').children().first().addClass('show');
    });
});
```

in ur style add

```
div{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.show{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Full code and working [Demo Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/j42BxaWdyuTZEpmlOTTc?p=preview)